# Block All in One SEO from altering site title

Tags: plugin-all-in-one-seo

The new version of AIOSP( v3.0 ) is altering site title forcibly and doing anything in the theme does not block it to do so !
How to prevent it from this stupid behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to completely remove it's title filter
First disable "force rewrites" in "performance"
Then add this code to theme "functions.php"

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_aioseo_wp_title', 1 );
function remove_aioseo_wp_title() {
    global $aiosp;

    if( isset( $aiosp ) ) {
        remove_filter( 'wp_title', array( $aiosp, 'wp_title' ), 20 );
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
This is the new code for v4.0

```
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_aioseo_wp_title', 0 );
function remove_aioseo_wp_title() {

    if( ! function_exists( 'aioseo' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $aioseo = aioseo();
    remove_action( 'wp', array( $aioseo->head, 'registerTitleHooks' ), 1000 );
}
```